# needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, java-native-interface

I want to implement AEs and RSA in my project.i downloaded pre built openssl and included in my project.   After including openssl in my project i am getting error as above mentioned.i searched on SO some answers mentioned to include **set_target_properties** in CMake(U can check my cmake below) but still no use.

My CMakeLists.txt

```
   # For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )
             add_library(openssl SHARED IMPORTED)
             set_target_properties (openssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.so )


# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

include_directories(jni/include/)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.a
                        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libssl.a
                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

and My build.graddle is here

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.manvish.prebuiltcrypto"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
                abiFilters "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

help me to resolve this issue?

The complete error log is here

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /home/manvish/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/manvish/Gajanand/PrebuiltCrypto/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a --target native-lib}
  ninja: error: '../../../../jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can guess that you get the cited error because you don't have `jniLibs/x86_64/lib/libcrypto.a`. Try to use

```
abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
```

Comment: Please paste full error log, the message you put in the question title is not enough out of context

Comment: Very good. You see that the error message says that file **libcrypto.a** does not exist at `../../../../jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a`. So try to give the correct path to this file.

Comment: Thank u sir.. Now library detected.

Comment: @AlexCohn I got the same issue. it seem like the So file is not available. Please check below error for same. Please guide me to resolved it.

Comment: error: '../../../../src/main/jniLibs/x86/libopencv_java3.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/x86/libnative-lib.so', missing and no known rule t
o make it

Comment: Here I am making an APK file. When I do run the app in debug mode then it works fine.

Comment: @idroidexplorer please describe your problem as a separate question in more detail. Explain how your files are organized. Usually, we keep opencv libraries where the package is installed, and not copy them to jniLibs.

Comment: Hello, I have this error. `Error:error: '../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libsmbclient.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libsamba_client.so', missing and no known rule to make it` but I dont know how to solve it. Please help me

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala this looks like an entirely different problem. Please open a separate question, and provide more details. For example: are you building `libsamba_client.so`? Can you build it for some other architecture? What is the content of your **jniLibs** directory?

Answer (score 1):

This error happend to me when upgrade targetSDKversion from 21 to 27. The last change of this horrible stage of my life as a Android programmer was this error:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':myProject:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
>     Build command failed.
>     Error while executing process C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\workspaces\android\myProject.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a --target myProject}
>     ninja: error: '../../../../src/main/libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libmyProject.so', missing and no known rule to make it

My app uses a own .so which uses funcions of libcrypto.so inside him, for that reason appers myproject.so

Change the old path for the new one, for that, you need to go to External Build Files/CMakeLists.txt in Android Studio (if dont appers in your Android Studio interface, go to your FileSystem and search it inside your project, and compile after realize this change).

If doens't exists, add set_target_properties:

```
set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
                   crypto-lib

                   # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
                   PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

                   # Provides the path to the library you want to import.${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
                   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcrypto.so )
```

To:

```
set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
                   crypto-lib

                   # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
                   PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

                   # Provides the path to the library you want to import.${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
                   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcrypto.so )
```

Now, build the project and run the app.

**Thing related**:

- Dont need to add crypto statically (is libcrypto, but his name is crypto).

> System.loadLibrary("crypto");

**Related info**:

- [Description of Android.mk](http://android.mk/)
- [Port to BoringSSl](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/) (no need to me to work the app)

I hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

My Solution was:

If parent folder of project has space or unsupported characters in folder's name, it all because of this.

Example : `C:/users/user/desktop/Android Studio Projects/Application Folder`

Change: `Android Studio Projects` => `AndroidStudioProjects`

It worked for me